# DialogFlow: The number of training phrases limited to 10 for all languages together

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant

We built our google assistant actions using Dialogflow. Each action has  multiple (5) languages and in each language there are  about 10 training phrases. Now the integration fails saying that the total training phrases should not exceed 10. We have 10 languages. Do we need to put just 2 training phrases for language? I don't think that would be enough for the Assistant to recognize the action. What is the solution to handle this issue?

Comment: Can you share a bit more about where you encounter the error and the message itself?

Comment: The error occurs when we try integration of intents to google assistant from Dialogflow.

Comment: Where does that happen? How would someone reproduce this error?

Comment: Create project in google action console. Create custom action and enable two languages (Ex: English and French). Add  an intent using DialogFlow for each language. Add 6 training Phrases for each intent in DialogFlow. Then try integrations in Dialog Flow. Select your intents and select Test. As total training phrases are 12, it gives error. If the total is less than 10 those intents will be added in Google action console to the actions project. This is same as this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187728545?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit of 10 intents and 10 training phrases per intent, but only the ones used for [implicit invocation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/discovery/implicit). In the other ones, the usual and much higher [Dialogflow limits](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/quotas#limit) apply.